# ESOCKETTIMEOUT in Postman when sending request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I am not able to resolve this. Went through all the forum post with similar issues but nothing helped me resolve this issue. I am getting ESOCKETTIMEOUT when trying to send request in postman. I am sharing screenshot of my code along with error in postman:-

[screenshot showing the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jJUq.png)

[My index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1JEU.png)

Comment: Make a request to "localhost:3000/" and check. Don't add "posts" at the end of the url

Comment: Did that but I am receiving 404 cannot post error

Comment: Do a get request

Comment: get request is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the culprit. All I had to do was to replace res.json with res.send on line 17 & 18. Appreciate Deekshith for taking time out to look into the problem. Thanks